# Can't log in to embedded Linux Buildroot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, buildroot, intel-galileo

I'm looking to install Linux onto an Intel Galileo Gen 2 utilizing [this](https://github.com/andy-shev/linux/tree/galileo) and [this](https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot) via installing onto an SD card.

I believe I have successfully done this, as during the boot sequence I am able to select Linux to boot from, however as soon as it starts booting from Linux, I am unable to interact with the Galileo anymore by say typing in my username and password when it comes time to login.

I'm unsure if my peripheral setup is wrong, if I need to install some more drivers to support I/O or something else.

I am viewing the logs from the Galileo via an [FTDI cable](https://www.instructables.com/Linux-Tutorial-For-Intel-Galileo-Gen-2/#step5) and currently have a keyboard plugged directly into the Galileo.

### Log data

- When I boot the Galileo, [this](https://justpaste.it/1kz1t) is what is logged.
- Interestingly, the
  flashing cursor stops flashing and is just steady when I get to the
  login screen, as if the device is sort of frozen
- However if I then
  say connect a keyboard, it recognizes it and outputs [this](https://justpaste.it/8reyv) log data.

Comment: *"I am unable to interact with the Galileo anymore by say typing in my username and password when it comes time to login."* -- Using what HW interface?  You only mention a FTDI serial connection and a keyboard.  Have you ever booted this board successfully to a shell prompt with another build or downloaded image?

Comment: That's a great point @sawdust, thank you. Seemingly I can't type into the default prompt. As it looks to be a different problem, closing this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Turns out it was a faulty FTDI cable!